# Parameter fitting in transistor simulations

Tags: electrical-engineering

What are good methods for black box model fitting? I have a set of experimental data, and a mathematical model (basically a set of differential equations) with adjustable parameters. The parameters should be adjusted so that the model reproduces the experimental data. I have some literature values to start, but simply with these values the curves produced by the model don't fit to the curves of the experiment (the literature values are to be regarded with a certain error anyway; the experimental data that I have to fit my model to is fortunately barely noisy).

I've been trying to get some results for two months, with results more than nothing but far from satisfactory. Lately what I've tried is an evolution algorithm, called [CMA-ES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMA-ES), but it takes a lot of time, becasue it needs a few hundred iterations, and one iteration involves solving the set of DEs several times, which takes at least 15 minutes. (Now that the better server at the lab died, it takes 50 minutes per iteration...) It gave the best results so far, but these were again not satisfactory.

Can you suggest some good methods to do the fitting?